# I don't know why categories are showing below post

Tags: theme-development

I have created a function which shows categories list. When I call it above the entry-header, It is also shown below content even I haven't call it there.

Also, the categories get duplicated e.g Our news category is shown three time.

My code looks like.

```
 if (!function_exists('category_renown')) :
    function category_renown() {
        $categories = get_the_category_list( esc_html__( ' ', 'openblogger' ));
        if ( $categories ) {
                printf( '<span class="catu-links">' . esc_html__( '%1$s', 'openblogger' ) . '</span>', $categories ); // WPCS: XSS OK.
            }
    }
endif;
```

Any help will be appreciated
I pointed out that the related posts is doing everything but still not finding solution.

```
<?php

// Adds custom image size for images in Related Posts section.
add_image_size( 'related', 400, 222, true );

// add_action( 'after_entry_footer', 'wg_related_posts', 12 );
function wg_related_posts() {
    global $do_not_duplicate;

    // If we are not on a single post page, abort.
    if ( ! is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    global $count;
    $count = 0;

    $related = '';

    $do_not_duplicate = array();

    // Get the tags for the current post.
    $tags = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'post_tag' );

    // Get the categories for the current post.
    $cats = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category' );

    // If we have some tags, run the tag query.
    if ( $tags ) {
        $query    = wg_related_tax_query( $tags, $count, 'tag' );
        $related .= $query['related'];
        $count    = $query['count'];
    }

    // If we have some categories and less than 3 posts, run the cat query.
    if ( $cats && $count <= 2 ) {
        $query    = wg_related_tax_query( $cats, $count, 'category' );
        $related .= $query['related'];
        $count    = $query['count'];
    }

    // End here if we don't have any related posts.
    if ( ! $related ) {
        return;
    }


    // Display the related posts section.
    echo '<div class="related">';
     if (get_theme_mod('related_posts-title') != ""){
     echo '<h3 class="related-title">'.get_theme_mod('related_posts-title').'</h3>';
 } else {
 echo '<h3 class="related-title">Related Posts</h3>';
 }
        echo '<div class="related-posts">' . $related . '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}

/**
 * The taxonomy query.
 *
 * @since  1.0.0
 * 
 * @param  array  $terms Array of the taxonomy's objects.
 * @param  int    $count The number of posts.
 * @param  string $type  The type of taxonomy, e.g: `tag` or `category`.
 *
 * @return string
 */
function wg_related_tax_query( $terms, $count, $type ) {
    global $do_not_duplicate;

    // If the current post does not have any terms of the specified taxonomy, abort.
    if ( ! $terms ) {
        return;
    }

    // Array variable to store the IDs of the posts.
    // Stores the current post ID to begin with.
    $post_ids = array_merge( array( get_the_ID() ), $do_not_duplicate );

    $term_ids = array();

    // Array variable to store the IDs of the specified taxonomy terms.
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $term_ids[] = $term->term_id;
    }

    $tax_query = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'post_format',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => array(
                'post-format-link',
                'post-format-status',
                'post-format-aside',
                'post-format-quote',
            ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ),
    );

 if (get_theme_mod('related-number') != ""){
    echo $showposts = get_theme_mod('related-number', 3 - $count);
} else {
     $showposts = 3 - $count;
 }
    //$showposts = 3 - $count;

    $args = array(
        $type . '__in'        => $term_ids,
        'post__not_in'        => $post_ids,
        'showposts'           => $showposts,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'tax_query'           => $tax_query,
    );

    $related  = '';

    $tax_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ( $tax_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $tax_query->have_posts() ) {
            $tax_query->the_post();

            $do_not_duplicate[] = get_the_ID();

            $count++;

            $title = get_the_title();

            $related .= '<div class="related-post">';

            $related .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to ' . $title . '">'.get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</a>';

            $related .= '<div class="related-post-info"><a class="related-post-title" href="' . get_permalink() . '" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to ' . $title . '">' . $title . '</a>';

            $related .= '<div class="related-post-date">' . get_the_date() . '</div>';

            $related .= '<div class="related-post-tags">' . related_tags() . '</div>';

            $related .= '<div class="related-post-categories">'. related_categories() . '</div></div>';

            $related .= '</div>';
        }
    }
    $sep = ',';

    wp_reset_postdata();

    $output = array(
        'related' => $related,
        'count'   => $count,
    );

    return $output;
}
```

this is the live preview image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that your are using undersocres starter theme to build your theme
and you probably copied the code from template-tags.php inside inc folder in your theme.
Now do this:

keep this code inside template-tags.php

```
function category_renown() {
    $categories = get_the_category_list( esc_html__( ' ', 'openblogger' ));
    if ( $categories ) {
            printf( '<span class="catu-links">' . esc_html__( '%1$s', 'openblogger' ) . '</span>', $categories ); // WPCS: XSS OK.
        }
}
```

copy your function inside content.php file like:

this is the content for content.php file

```
<?php
/**
 * Template part for displaying posts
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/
 *
 * @package xyz
 */

?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php category_renown(); ?>
        <?php
        if ( is_singular() ) :
            the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
        else :
            the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' );
        endif;

        if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) :
            ?>
            <div class="entry-meta">
                <?php
                xyz_posted_on();
                xyz_posted_by();
                ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
        <?php endif; ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <?php xyz_post_thumbnail(); ?>

    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php
        the_content( sprintf(
            wp_kses(
                /* translators: %s: Name of current post. Only visible to screen readers */
                __( 'Continue reading<span class="screen-reader-text"> "%s"</span>', 'xyz' ),
                array(
                    'span' => array(
                        'class' => array(),
                    ),
                )
            ),
            get_the_title()
        ) );

        wp_link_pages( array(
            'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'xyz' ),
            'after'  => '</div>',
        ) );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    <footer class="entry-footer">
        <?php xyz_entry_footer(); ?>
    </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
</article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
```

now you need to remove the following code in template-tags.php file inside function xyz_entry_footer():

```
$categories = get_the_category_list( esc_html__( ' ', 'openblogger' ));
if ( $categories ) {
        printf( '<span class="catu-links">' . esc_html__( '%1$s', 'openblogger' ) . '</span>', $categories ); // WPCS: XSS OK.
    }
```

final version of template-tags.php should be:

```
<?php
/**
 * Custom template tags for this theme
 *
 * Eventually, some of the functionality here could be replaced by core features.
 *
 * @package xyz
 */

if ( ! function_exists( 'xyz_posted_on' ) ) :
    /**
     * Prints HTML with meta information for the current post-date/time.
     */
    function xyz_posted_on() {
        $time_string = '<time class="entry-date published updated" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time>';
        if ( get_the_time( 'U' ) !== get_the_modified_time( 'U' ) ) {
            $time_string = '<time class="entry-date published" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time><time class="updated" datetime="%3$s">%4$s</time>';
        }

        $time_string = sprintf( $time_string,
            esc_attr( get_the_date( DATE_W3C ) ),
            esc_html( get_the_date() ),
            esc_attr( get_the_modified_date( DATE_W3C ) ),
            esc_html( get_the_modified_date() )
        );

        $posted_on = sprintf(
            /* translators: %s: post date. */
            esc_html_x( 'Posted on %s', 'post date', 'xyz' ),
            '<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">' . $time_string . '</a>'
        );

        echo '<span class="posted-on">' . $posted_on . '</span>'; // WPCS: XSS OK.

    }
endif;

if ( ! function_exists( 'xyz_posted_by' ) ) :
    /**
     * Prints HTML with meta information for the current author.
     */
    function xyz_posted_by() {
        $byline = sprintf(
            /* translators: %s: post author. */
            esc_html_x( 'by %s', 'post author', 'xyz' ),
            '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="' . esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ) . '">' . esc_html( get_the_author() ) . '</a></span>'
        );

        echo '<span class="byline"> ' . $byline . '</span>'; // WPCS: XSS OK.

    }
endif;

if ( ! function_exists( 'xyz_entry_footer' ) ) :
    /**
     * Prints HTML with meta information for the categories, tags and comments.
     */
    function xyz_entry_footer() {
        // Hide tag text for pages.
        if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) {

            /* translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma */
            $tags_list = get_the_tag_list( '', esc_html_x( ', ', 'list item separator', 'xyz' ) );
            if ( $tags_list ) {
                /* translators: 1: list of tags. */
                printf( '<span class="tags-links">' . esc_html__( 'Tagged %1$s', 'xyz' ) . '</span>', $tags_list ); // WPCS: XSS OK.
            }
        }

        if ( ! is_single() && ! post_password_required() && ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) ) {
            echo '<span class="comments-link">';
            comments_popup_link(
                sprintf(
                    wp_kses(
                        /* translators: %s: post title */
                        __( 'Leave a Comment<span class="screen-reader-text"> on %s</span>', 'xyz' ),
                        array(
                            'span' => array(
                                'class' => array(),
                            ),
                        )
                    ),
                    get_the_title()
                )
            );
            echo '</span>';
        }

        edit_post_link(
            sprintf(
                wp_kses(
                    /* translators: %s: Name of current post. Only visible to screen readers */
                    __( 'Edit <span class="screen-reader-text">%s</span>', 'xyz' ),
                    array(
                        'span' => array(
                            'class' => array(),
                        ),
                    )
                ),
                get_the_title()
            ),
            '<span class="edit-link">',
            '</span>'
        );
    }
endif;

function category_renown() {
    $categories = get_the_category_list( esc_html__( ' ', 'openblogger' ));
    if ( $categories ) {
            printf( '<span class="catu-links">' . esc_html__( '%1$s', 'openblogger' ) . '</span>', $categories ); // WPCS: XSS OK.
        }
}
if ( ! function_exists( 'xyz_post_thumbnail' ) ) :
    /**
     * Displays an optional post thumbnail.
     *
     * Wraps the post thumbnail in an anchor element on index views, or a div
     * element when on single views.
     */
    function xyz_post_thumbnail() {
        if ( post_password_required() || is_attachment() || ! has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( is_singular() ) :
            ?>

            <div class="post-thumbnail">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </div><!-- .post-thumbnail -->

        <?php else : ?>

        <a class="post-thumbnail" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
            <?php
            the_post_thumbnail( 'post-thumbnail', array(
                'alt' => the_title_attribute( array(
                    'echo' => false,
                ) ),
            ) );
            ?>
        </a>

        <?php
        endif; // End is_singular().
    }
endif;
```

I just assumed you are building theme using underscores starter theme. If not please add more code ( where you are calling that function )

another thing you may have done more changes to starter theme, so be careful before copying and pasting this code.

Comment: yes to make theme development easier i used underscores. I am using the same code and i am this way but the problem persists. I don't know why it is showing below posts. Remember everything is fine but showing below content

Comment: make some changes ( like insert paragraph ) in content.php file to make sure it's using this file to display posts. If it's the correct file you'll see that text in your browser when viewing the post.
and try browsing in incognito mode as well, sometime it may be cache issue

Comment: also make sure you removed the code to display category list inside function xyz_entry_footer() ( in your case inside openblogger_entry_footer() function )

Comment: all the problem is created by related_posts. i am uploading the code please checkit

Comment: where are you calling the function wg_related_tax_query() ?